# How do I specify specific parameters in a Swagger response rather than use `allOf`?

Tags: rest, api, swagger, openapi

I have defined some parameters using annotations in my model (PHP) and using `darkaonline/l5-swagger` to compile the lot to JSON. The annotations are like this:

```
/** 
* @OA\Schema(schema="UserModel", required={""})
*/
class User extends Authenticatable
{

/**
 * @OA\Property(
 *   property="id",
 *   type="integer",
 *   format="int64",
 *   description="The unique identifier of a user"
 * )
 */

/**
 * @OA\Property(
 *   property="email",
 *   type="string",
 *   example="john@example.com",
 *   description="The email address of a user"
 * )
 */

/**
 * @OA\Property(
 *   property="password",
 *   type="string",
 *   description="The password of a user"
 * )
 */

/**
 * @OA\Schema(
 *   schema="CreateUser",
 *   type="object",
 *   allOf={
 *     @OA\Schema(ref="#/components/schemas/UserModel"),
 *   }
 * )
 */
```

In the schema that I have defined for the payload I have `allOf` which will include all properties. This does work as far as loading the doc goes but I obviously don't want properties like `id` there. I assume there's an alternative to `allOf` that will allow me to define which properties I do want but I can't seem to find it.

Does anyone know what it may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no alternative in openapi to `allOf` that will allow you to choose which properties from a different object you want to use. If you really need that functionality you can define different objects containing each field separately and then reuse the ones that you really need. Something like that:

```
UserIdModel:
  properties:
    id: 
      type: integer
      ...
UserEmailModel:
  properties:
    email:
      type: string
      ...
UserPasswordModel:
  properties:
    password:
      type: string
      ...
CreateUser:
  allOf:
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserEmailModel'
    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserPasswordModel'
```

Comment: That's really annoying. It means I have to repeat properties. For example, `email` would exist in the creation payload as well as the response. However others like id and password do not.

Comment: @michael, I originally misunderstood what you meant and I have worked it out. The annotation examples can be seen here: https://github.com/zircote/swagger-php/blob/master/docs/Getting-started.md

Thanks for you help.